# Problem while redirecting the output of the time command if the input command output in stderr

Tags: bash, time, io-redirection

I have a problem with this command :

```
(/usr/bin/time -f %Es MY_PROGRAM 1> /dev/null) 2>&1
```

I want it to **only** output the time it took to run (without any other info). The `time` command outputs the time in stderr but since MY_PROGRAM (the program I time) also outputs logs in stderr, the output of the command is polluted by MY_PROGRAM stderr output.

Like this :

```
$ (/usr/bin/time -f %Es MY_PROGRAM 1> /dev/null) 2>&1
BLABLABLA BLABLABLA BLABLABLA
BLABLABLA BLABLABLA
BLABLABLA
0:30.16s
```

I'm only interested in the final time so I would like to remove the "BLABLABLA" to parse the final time.

Anyone knows how to pull that off ?

Thx!

Comment: To discard: `/pathto/time ... 2>&1 1>/dev/null | tail -1` (don't need subshell, just put 2> _before_ 1>); to put in a file: `/pathto/time -f %Es bash -c "MYPROG 1>/dev/null 2>errfile"`

Comment: You just avoid the problem but at least it works. Thx m8!